# How to create new div but appears beneath previous div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create two divs with images as background. So how do I make the later created div to appear under the already exist div. As I known, it will appear on top of it. It is like in Photoshop, you can move the layers forward and backward. Any suggestion on what code I should use?

Here's my code.
So I want the "mist" div to appear under "gaze" div.

```
var gaze= document.createElement('div');
        gaze.setAttribute("id", "gaze");
        gaze.setAttribute("style", "width:716px; height: 158px; background-image: url(images/gaze.png); opacity:1.0; position:absolute; left: "+window.innerWidth*0.187+"px; top: "+window.innerHeight*0.202+"px")
        document.body.appendChild(gaze);
        gaze.addEventListener('click',fadeIn, false);
        dim();
    }


    function dim () {
        gaze = document.getElementById("gaze");
        gaze.style.cursor = "pointer";
        gaze_opacity = parseFloat(gaze.style.opacity).toFixed(1);
        gaze_opacity-= .1;
        gaze.style.opacity=gaze_opacity;
        if (gaze_opacity>0.1) {
            setTimeout('dim()', 300);
        }
    }

    function fadeIn() {
        gaze = document.getElementById("gaze");
        gaze.style.opacity = 1.0;
        gaze.removeEventListener('click',fadeIn,false);
        gaze.addEventListener('click',mist, false);
    }

    function mist() {
        var mist= document.createElement('div');
        mist.setAttribute("id", "mist");
        mist.setAttribute("style", "width:1048px; height: 720px; background-image: url(images/mist.png); opacity:1.0; position:absolute; left: "+window.innerWidth*0+"px; top: "+window.innerHeight*0+"px")
        document.body.appendChild(mist);
```

Comment: you will need to use CSS

relative and absolute positioning are your friend here along with a z-index value

please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `z-index` property in the css.
Give more `z-index` value to the div which you want to appear on top
and give a lesser `z-index' value to the one which you wanna appear beneath

`<div id="Topdiv"style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:100px;left:100px">`

**THIS WILL BE ON TOP**

> > `</div>`

```
 <div id="Bottomdiv"style="position:absolute;z-index:1;top:100px;left:100px"></div>
```

and for the code that you have shared add the below line in document.ready function

```
$("#mist").css("z-index","1000);
```